# Convert date format to dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ii (2018-08-05T06:22:30Z) in PHP

Tags: php

I have date format like this (2018-08-05T06:22:30Z). I need to convert it to dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ii format.

I have tried this so far:

```
$dt ="2018-08-05T06:22:30Z";
$dt1 = date('d-m-Y HH:mm:ii', strtotime($dt));
```

Output of above code is **05-08-2018 0202:0808:2222**.

How can I convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ii` format?

Comment: What's the intended output of `"2018-08-05T06:22:30Z"` ?

Comment: I wonder why you are duplicating the format codes for time but not the codes for date...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your time format is doubling up the format letters - `HH:mm:ii` you are also confusing the Month (m) and the minutes (i), it should be `H:i:s` which gives...

```
05-08-2018 07:22:30
```

Comment: I am stuck in another issue now. My Query is not returning value by using this format. SELECT id,title,description
FROM post_feed where  `dates` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY dates DESC LIMIT 100

Answer (score 1):

Change $dt1 to be

```
$dt1 = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($dt));
```

You should check [PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to see the format parameters. The ones I changed in your code were as follows;

i - which gets you the minutes with leading zeros
s - which gets you the seconds with leading zeros